# heroku logs -t immediately returns Log stream timed out. Please try again

Tags: heroku

As per [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#real-time-tail), I would expect to see `Log stream timed out. Please try again.` after 1 hour of inactivity

> A real-time tail session is automatically terminated after one hour of
>   inactivity.

However, I'm seeing this message immediately after running `heroku logs -t`

I checked `heroku status` but it returns no known issues.

Comment: You just have to wait for around 30 min and try again.

Comment: @DiegoMolina was that because it's a heroku issue? If so, it seems odd that `heroku status` would return no known issues?

Comment: I don't think it was a heroku issue. I might think is a way of saving memory.